# jQuery - bind an event to each element in a dynamically generated list

Tags: jquery, dynamic, each, bind

I have several `li` elements that get added to a `ul` list dynamically. In each of the `li` elements, there's a button. I want to attach a click event to each button, and within the event handler, I want to get properties unique to the `li` whose button was clicked.

This (non-functional) code illustrates what I want:

```
$('ul > li > button').each('click', function(){

    var asdf = $('somehow access any arbitrary element in the li whose button was clicked').html();

});
```

My current solution (below) works, but it forces me to set an id for each `li` that indicates its position in the list, which for various reasons I'd rather not do.

```
// In the response function of the AJAX call that populates the list:

$('ul > li').each(function(i){
  $('button', this).click(function(){

    var name = $('ul > li#item'+i+' > .name').html();

  });
});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Try `$('ul').find('li').forEach(function(item) { $(item).find('button').click(...);})) `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @Andreas: The snag here is that I need access to all elements of the li, of which button is only one. Using the solution offered in that question, wouldn't I just have access to the button's context?

Comment: No -> `$("ul").on("click", "button", function(e) { var btn = $(this), li = button.closest("li"); ... })`

Comment: I agree with @Andreas suggestion of using the on() function.

Comment: However the right solution has been initially proposed by @DinoMyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend something like

```
$('ul > li > button').click(function(){
    var parent_li = $(this).parents('li'); //You can use class of li.
    var name = parent_li.html(); // Or whatever you want. In this case $(this) is the clicked element
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I would only have access to the button's context, whereas I need access to the whole li. Maybe I could do something with outerHTML, but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Didn't understand that before. Check my edit. Hope this helps

Comment: D'oh. parents() was what I needed. Combined this with .on() so I don't need to do it in the ajax response.

Comment: This solution won't work if you add any `li`s after appending this `click` event. You need the @DinoMyte solution.

Comment: @Ermakov yes of course, but he can set a class in parent <li> and use parents() with that class. It depends on what Tyler needs.

Comment: I thought he needed what he wrote in the first line: `I have several li elements that get added to a ul list dynamically`. How this solution will work if a new `li` is added?

Comment: But the button belongs to the new dynamically added <li> elements, so parents() will find the desired. But as i said before, he can set a specific class to the <li> he wants to capture and use that class in parents().

Comment: Each `button` is inside a `li`. When he adds a `li` with the `button` inside , a click event will not be binded because binding has happened before and only for the buttons that existed in DOM at that time. The `parents` thing has nothing to do with that - it is just a method to find elements existing in the DOM at the moment of binding. It won't embrace new elements.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delegate the `click` event by using `.on()` instead of binding the `click` event when the elements are dynamically created in the DOM.

```
 $(document).on("click", 'ul',function(){    
    var name = $(this).find('li#' + num).html();
    alert(name);
  });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/Lkb0s60n/

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single
>   event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.

Source : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/WrZjEv)

**JS:**

```
// In the response function of the AJAX call that populates the list:
jQuery('ul > li').each(function(i){
  jQuery('button', this).click(function(){

    var name = $(this).text();
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
// e.g. "1" or "2"    
console.log(name);
// e.g. "one" or "two"    
console.log(className);    
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="one">1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="two">2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="three">3</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The click() function will only bind itself to the items present in the DOM at the moment where the document is loaded. What you need to use is jQUery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

For on() to work you need an element that exists in the DOM when the script is loaded in this case

```
<ul class="myList">
```

With the on() function you add the click event to the selected elements inside the UL.myList. The code

```
$('.myList').on('click', 'li > button', function(){...});
```

Would be bindind the click event to all buttons inside an li , that are present inside your UL.myList. These will be binded even if the li>button elements are added after an AJAX call

---

Example:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addLi').on('click', function() {
      $(".myList").append($('<li  data-mydata="The new one"><button type="button">btn</button></li>'));
    });

    $('.myList').on('click', 'li > button', function() {
      var thisButton = $(this); //Get the button that was clicked
      var prnt = thisButton.parent(); //Get its parent
      var msg = "I was clicked" + thisButton.prop('tagName') + " My parent is " + prnt.data('mydata'); //Retrieve data of the parent
      alert(msg);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li data-mydata="The one">
    <button type="button">btn</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="addLi">Add LI</button>
```